# With extension, access current Google Chrome guide

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension for Google Chrome using HTML, CSS, JavaScript. I need to access the current tab to do automation but I can't access the current tab.

I tried with this code:

```js
async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  // `tab` will either be a `tabs.Tab` instance or `undefined`.
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}
```